# Trouble with converting json string in php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, ajax

I want to send a JSON string in JavaScript and then, with encoding php function, convert it to an array.

Once converted the string with JavaScript and sent with Ajax to php page, I can't convert it to an array.

That's the code.

```js
function goJsonAjaxPhp()
{
    var myObject ={name:"Andreas",surname:"Grech",age:20};
    var str_json = JSON.stringify(myObject);
    var xhr;
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.HMLHTTP");
    }
    xhr.onreadystatechange = handler;
    xhr.open("POST","page_php.php",true);
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
    xhr.send(str_json);
                                   
    function handler()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            document.getElementById("idResult").innerHTML= xhr.responseText;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<button onclick=goJsonAjaxPhp()> Json Ajax-PHP </button>
<button onclick=goJsonPhp()> Json Only-PHP </button>
<button onclick=goJsonJavascript()> Json Javascript </button>

<div id=idResult></div>
```

```
header("Content-Type: application/json;ì");
$str_json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$arrayPHP = (array) json_encode($str_json,TRUE);
var_dump($arrayPHP);
```

This is the php output

[image]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Surely you're wanting `json_decode` in your PHP...

Comment: I already tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Explain how it didn't work please. Add your debugging steps.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know how to check debugging steps, I'm sorry

Comment: I solved this, you were right from the beginning! Thank you so much and please sorry

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
$arrayPHP = (array) json_encode($str_json,TRUE);
```

try

```
$arrayPHP = (array) json_decode($str_json,TRUE);
```

Comment: You can also get rid of the `(array)` casting since that's what the `true` does in the second param. Casting it to an array would also stop you from seeing if it has returned `null` which implies an error in decoding.

Comment: Debug as proposed above and then post error message so that we can identify possible source of bug